# How to fix: Tables rearranging on sharepoint pages, after save

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-server

I have encountered a bug when editing our publishing sites.

Within the editor or content of the page, we use tables to list certain specifications.

Sometimes, after saving, the tables rearrange, adding additional columns and moving the text between cells. Words get halved.

I am still unable to reproduce this issue. So far it seems to happen on some wild occasions.

Has anyone encountered the same Problem?
Has anyone got an Idea for a fix?

We are using Sharepoint Server 2016 on-premise.

BR & Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems when working with tables or formatting in a content editor web part.  To me when I kept trying it eventually worked.  Sometimes I would have to wait, then make my changes, then save and it would finally work.  Seems like a SP quirk to me.